# Reading PCI device memory registers in windows

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, pci, pci-bus

I need to read the HBA memory registers of the AHCI controller sitting on the PCI bus of the system. I have a driver using which I can read the config space of all the PCI devices in the system (using ReadConfig and WriteConfig). Through this I'm able to get the ABAR content which is the last BAR in AHCI device's config space. Now, I need to read the values of these memory registers. Does anybody has any idea how to do this? PCITree is able to do this, so I know that this is possible.

I'm new to driver development, so any help would be greatly appreciated... :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can use winio to access memory under Windows NT/2000/XP/2003/Vista/7 and 2008. Please reference the [link](http://www.internals.com/) and click "winio" to download and use. There are samples and sources within it and you can easily transfer to your application.